# leaflet remove layer from event

Tags: events, leaflet, layer

please help me! It's my simple code:

```
var сluster = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
сluster.addTo(map);
var obj = L.marker([56.34265, 30.523397]);
сluster.addLayer(obj);
```

Why this code:

```
сluster.removeLayer(obj);
```

successfully removes obj from cluster, but this:

```
obj.on('click', function(){
    сluster.removeLayer(obj);
});
```

don't removes on click

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
сluster.on('click', function (a) {
   сluster.removeLayer(a.layer);
});
```